# The reason why it's possible to use helper method like current_user, authenticate_user!, and so on without including any module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

The title is my question.

[devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) provide us many useful methods like `current_user`, `authenticate_user!`, and so on. I want to know why is it possible to use them without including any module like below.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Those method's definition is [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L43)

Somebody please help me！

Comment: When you use `devise_for` in your `routes.rb` Devise looks up your ApplicationController and defines the methods dynamically. You really need to look at the source code if you want to understand how it works in detail.

Comment: Complementing what max just said above: Devise, like most of gems, use metaprogramming in Ruby to achieve its goals. The source code Devise uses to generate dynamic methods for `current_` can be seen at: https://github.dev/heartcombo/devise/tree/master/lib/devise/controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [devise included its helper methods into ActionController](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails.rb#L20-L22)  on behalf of you when Rails `on_load`

```rb
# devise/rails.rb
module Devise
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    # ...
    initializer "devise.url_helpers" do
      Devise.include_helpers(Devise::Controllers)
    end
    # ...
end

# devise.rb
  # ...
  def self.include_helpers(scope)
    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
      include scope::Helpers if defined?(scope::Helpers)
      include scope::UrlHelpers
    end

    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
      include scope::UrlHelpers
    end
  end
  # ...
```

I saw many 3rd gems using [on_load](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/LazyLoadHooks.html) to include their methods (or themselves) into Rails core, maybe it's a typical way to do that (allows Rails to lazily load a lot of components and thus making the app boot faster). If you install some gems and you could use their methods on your model/controller/view then those gems did the same thing `devise` did above.

About those methods `current_user`, `authenticate_user!` ... they are [dynamic methods devise will generate](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L88-L139) when it did `include scope::Helpers` into Rails (see code above and the link).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really what I wanted know! I couldn't reach the way to define dynamic methods and the way to load them using `on_load` method.

Answer (score 0):

So one very good thing about rails is the fact that you get a lot of things for free out of the box. One of these things at the top level is autoloading.

So in the case of Devise. When you install Devise and run the `generate` command, you get a `devise.rb` file inside of your `config/initializers/` folder. This file is always autoloaded by rails on server startup and reload. That's how all these methods are able to be use these devise methods without importing anything.

Read more at [rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)